# tree: Is there a way to maintain visibility of outer level directory labels when scrolling?

Tags: linux, vi, tree

When you generate a tree for a large directory base with innumerable sub-directories and associated files, with `-a` option, often you get a large file with thousands of lines. While traversing the tree depicted within this file, it often becomes difficult to keep track of which directory you are in at any given point in time, as you descend deeper into the tree. As you scroll down the file from within a text editor like vi, you can lose track of the outer level directory labels.

So my question is, is there a way to overcome this issue? Is it possible at all to get some kind of perspective of the outer level directory labels, as you descend deeper into the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tree` utility on Linux has a `-f` option that lists each directory entry with its relative pathname:

```
$ tree -f ufw
ufw
├── ufw/after6.rules
├── ufw/after.init
├── ufw/after.rules
├── ufw/applications.d
│   ├── ufw/applications.d/cups
│   ├── ufw/applications.d/openssh-server
│   └── ufw/applications.d/postfix
├── ufw/before6.rules
├── ufw/before.init
├── ufw/before.rules
├── ufw/sysctl.conf
├── ufw/ufw.conf
├── ufw/user6.rules
└── ufw/user.rules

1 directory, 13 files
```

This would allow you to always know the exact pathname for each entry, relative to the top-level directory.